# MPAndroidChart with multiple line chart with different scales

Tags: android, android-library, mpandroidchart

Is there any possibility to achive chart with multiple line charts with different scales?

[image]

I was trying to achive it with CombinedChart but without any satisfactory result.

Maybe another chart library would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone needs to have two scale chart - I finally used [GraphView library](http://www.android-graphview.org).

It is providing this option.